# Sequelizejs schema sync does not return

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I run this [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) code with `node script.js`

```
const Sequelize = require('./node_modules/sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://user:pw@localhost:5432/db')

const customlayer = sequelize.define('customlayer', {
  ogc_fid: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    field: 'ogc_fid',
    validate: {isInt: true},
    primaryKey: true
  },
  wkb_geometry: {
    type: Sequelize.GEOMETRY('POINT'),
    field: 'wkb_geometry',
    allowNull: false
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    allowNull: true
  }
})

customlayer.sync({force: true}).catch(err => console.log(err.message))
```

It works (No errors in the log output and in Postgres the table is created) but it does not return to a normal terminal prompt..., so I have to do Ctrl+C to proceed in the terminal. Since I am using this as part of an Ansible script I need to script to return so Ansible can continue. How can I make it return?

Answer (score 0):

To return you need to close the connection manually when you're done, like:

```
customlayer.sync({force: true})
  .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
  .finally(() => sequelize.close());
```